# I believe my algrorithm is incorrect for calculating duration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an algorithim where it calculates the total duration remaining. The format of the duration is '00 Hrs 00 Mins 00 Secs'. How the calculation works is like this for example:

if total duration remaning is 01 Hrs 30 Mins 20 Secs and user enters in duration 00 Hrs 50 Mins 00 Secs and adds the row, then 01 Hrs 30 Mins 20 Secs minus 00 Hrs 50 Mins 00 Secs will make new total duration remaining equal 00 Hrs 40 Mins 20 Secs.

If the total duration goes into negative then format goes like this : - 00 Hrs 00 Mins 00 Secs

I have a couple of problems though:

**Problem 1:**
Lets say total duration remaining is '00 Hrs 00 Mins 50 Secs'. Then if I add 00 Hrs 00 Mins 50 Secs twice, the total duration remaining should equal '- 00 Hrs 00 Mins 50 Secs'

But instead it is displaying this ' - 00 Hrs 01 Mins 0-10 Secs'.

**Problem 2:**
Lets say total duration remaining is '00 Hrs 50 Mins 00 Secs'. Then if I add 00 Hrs 50 Mins 00 Secs twice, the total duration remaining should equal '- 00 Hrs 50 Mins 00 Secs'

But instead it is displaying this ' - 01 Hrs 0-10 Mins 00 Secs.

This is a strange problem. But I beleive this problem is happening because of my algrorithm. So my question is that does anyone know how to fix the algrorithm if the algrorithm is at fault?

Below is the code:

```
var format = duration.match(/(\d\d)/ig),
hours = parseInt(format[0], 10),
mins = parseInt(format[1], 10),
secs = parseInt(format[2], 10);


function calculateDuration()
{
    var totalduration = duration;  
    var sign = '';
    var tmp_hours = 0;
    var tmp_mins = 0;
    var tmp_secs = 0;

    $("#qandatbl td.duration input").each(function (){
        tmp_format = $(this).val().match(/(\d\d)/ig),
        tmp_hours += parseInt(tmp_format[0], 10),
        tmp_mins += parseInt(tmp_format[1], 10),
        tmp_secs += parseInt(tmp_format[2], 10);

    });

tmp_mins += Math.floor(tmp_secs / 60);
tmp_secs = tmp_secs % 60;
tmp_hours += Math.floor(tmp_mins / 60);
tmp_mins = tmp_mins % 60;

    newH = hours - tmp_hours;
    newM = mins - tmp_mins;
    newS = secs - tmp_secs;

    if( newS < 0 ) {
        newS += 60;
        newM--;
    }
    if( newM < 0 ) {
        newM += 60;
        newH--;
    }       

    if(newH < 0) {
        newM = Math.abs(newM - 60);
        newH = Math.abs(newH + 1);

        sign = '- ';
    }      

    checkedH = (newH < 10 ? '0' : '') + newH;
    checkedM = (newM < 10 ? '0' : '') + newM;
    checkedS = (newS < 10 ? '0' : '') + newS;

    new_duration = sign + checkedH + ' Hrs ' + checkedM + ' Mins ' + checkedS + ' Secs';


    $("#total-duration").text(new_duration);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You haven't shown the whole code. Where do the values for *hours*, *mins* and *secs* come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***updated answer***

Rewrote the algorithm to deal with seconds only

```
var format = duration.match(/(\d\d)/ig),
hours = parseInt(format[0], 10),
mins = parseInt(format[1], 10),
secs = parseInt(format[2], 10);

function secondsFromTime(timeString){
    var format = timeString.match(/(\d\d)/ig),
        h = parseInt(format[0], 10),
        m = parseInt(format[1], 10),
        s = parseInt(format[2], 10);

    return (h*3600) + (m*60) + s;
}

function calculateDuration()
{
    var totalduration = secondsFromTime(duration);
    var sign = '';
    var durationchange = 0;

    $("#qandatbl td.duration input").each(function (){
        durationchange += secondsFromTime(this.value);
    });

    sign = (totalduration < durationchange ) ? '-' : '';
    finalduration = Math.abs(totalduration - durationchange);

    checkedH = ('0' + Math.floor(finalduration / 3600)).slice(-2);
    checkedM = ('0' + Math.floor((finalduration % 3600) / 60)).slice(-2);
    checkedS = ('0' + Math.floor(finalduration % 60)).slice(-2);

    new_duration = sign + checkedH + ' Hrs ' + checkedM + ' Mins ' + checkedS + ' Secs';


    $("#total-duration").text(new_duration);
}
```

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/4xjcW/1/

---

***original answer***
Use the `Math.abs` to get the absolute value..

```
checkedH = (Math.abs(newH) < 10 ? '0' : '') + Math.abs(newH);
checkedM = (Math.abs(newM) < 10 ? '0' : '') + Math.abs(newM);
checkedS = (Math.abs(newS) < 10 ? '0' : '') + Math.abs(newS);
```

The problem is that you are returning `0` as a string and adding `-10` so it becomes `0-10`

Comment: If I use your code then previously it showed - 00 Hrs 00 Mins 0-50 Secs, now it is showing - 00 Hrs 00 Mins 050, it needs to show - 00 Hrs 00 Mins 50 Secs.

Comment: @user1131869 updated answer.. you need to use the absolute value for the check as well as the correct check should be `< 10` and `> -10`

Comment: It now displays - 00 Hrs 01 Mins 10 Secs, it should be - 00 Hrs 00 Mins 50 Secs. This is a tough algrorithm to sort out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the weird notation is because of the string concatenation you are doing in these lines:

```
checkedH = (newH < 10 ? '0' : '') + newH;
checkedM = (newM < 10 ? '0' : '') + newM;
checkedS = (newS < 10 ? '0' : '') + newS;
```

If a number of seconds/minutes/hours is negative, it is obviously < 10 so it will get added to '0'. The reason your number for minutes will be negative is indeed an error in your algorithm.

The way I would set this up is, instead of going through all values separately, just translate to a total number of seconds, do the calculation and translate back. Something like this:

```
tmp_secs= parseInt(tmp_format[0], 10) * 3600
    + parseInt(tmp_format[1], 10) * 60
    + parseInt(tmp_format[2], 10);
old_secs= hours * 3600 + mins * 60 + secs;

new_secs= old_secs-tmp_secs;

new_duration= (new_secs<0?'-':'') + Math.floor(new_secs/3600) + ' Hrs '
    + Math.floor((new_secs%3600)/60) + ' Mins '
    + Math.floor(new_secs%60) + ' Secs';
```

Hope it helps.

**Edit**

Replace the content of your calculateDuration function by the following:

```
var tmp_secs= 0;
var old_secs= hours * 3600 + mins * 60 + secs;

$("#qandatbl td.duration input").each(function (){
    tmp_secs += parseInt(tmp_format[0], 10) * 3600
        + parseInt(tmp_format[1], 10) * 60
        + parseInt(tmp_format[2], 10);
}

new_secs= old_secs-tmp_secs;
abs_secs= Math.abs(new_secs);

new_duration= (new_secs<0?'-':'') + Math.floor(abs_secs/3600) + ' Hrs '
    + Math.floor((abs_secs%3600)/60) + ' Mins '
    + Math.floor(abs_secs%60) + ' Secs';

$("#total-duration").text(new_duration);
```

I haven't tested this, but I think it should work. Good luck!

Comment: How do you put your code into my code, I am confused on where to put it and what my code should look like on the page

Comment: It doesn't change total duration remainnig when I add a duration?